# Am I able to use a boolean parameter in a controller method when it's passed using a path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, boolean

This is in my index view and I want to access the like: false/true parameter

```
    <%= link_to like_theory_path(theory, like: true), method: :post do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> 
      &nbsp
      <%= theory.thumbs_up_total %>
    <% end %>
    &nbsp
    &nbsp
    <%= link_to like_theory_path(theory, like: false), method: :post do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i>
      &nbsp
      <%= theory.thumbs_down_total %>
    <% end %>
```

This is in my controller

```
    if :like

      if like.like
        like.delete
      else
        like.delete
        like = Like.create(like: params[:like], theorist: current_user,  theory: @theory)
        like.valid?
      end

  else
    binding.pry
    if like.like
      like.delete
      like = Like.create(like: params[:like], theorist: current_user, theory: @theory)
      like.valid?
    else
      like.delete
    end

  end
```

So no matter if :like is true or false it never hits the else statement.

Am I using this correctly or is it technically not a parameter at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `link_to` helper passes arguments via the `params` hash. The `params` hash contains values of type `string`, so no, you can't pass a boolean value.

What you can do, however, is passing some other representation of a boolean, like "1" or "0", or "true" or "false" and creating an actual boolean value corresponding to those passed values within your controller method.

You might want to create a virtual attribute so that the string `like` doesn't conflict with your model's boolean `like` field.